# Is There an HTML Tidy tool/library for asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, htmltidy

I love how the html tidy tool works online. Is there a tool for this that beitifies html in real time?

Comment: In Visual Studio do this: Edit->Advanced->Format Document

Answer (score 0):

There is [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), which has been around for quite a while. It's written in C, but has has several [wrappers](http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html), including .Net. Here are a few more links that may find useful.

http://geoffmclane.com/tidy/tidy_06.htm

http://int64.org/projects/tidy-binaries

http://www.nextdesigns.ca/articles/tidy.aspx